# Event installed with bind $.mouseEvents.over never triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm searching for several days why the mouseOver event on div is never triggered.
The div appears like this in the html code : 
When inspecting the div with the Dev tools of Chrome, it appears that it is visible and at the right place.

The event is bound with this code :

```
$('.next-button').bind($.mouseEvents.over, function() {

        console.log('hover');
        $(this).addClass('next-button-hover');

})
```

The event listeners in the dev tools of Chrome says that the event is correctly registered. But this event is never triggered.

This problem may be seen on this temporary url : http://5.135.29.181:880/attachments/0000000019/fr/index.html

(This question is related to turnjs that seems to be unsupported.)

Thanks in advance for any help.

Best regards,

Guy

Comment: That's because of CSS `overflow: hidden;` set on `.magazine` container. The buttons is out of bounds and unclickable (because hidden)

Comment: It is the solution. Thanks a lot.